# Send XML object by parameter to a WebService published on a WebLogic server

Tags: oracle, web-services, weblogic

I am trying to send an XML object to a WebService that I published on a WebLogic server, but even if I do this object it is always received as null.

Here is the code of the WebService and the way in which I send the XML.
Any ideas ?

Code JAVA
Service method:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "ConsultarRecibosPendientes")
    @WebResult(name = "ConsultarRecibosPendientesResult")
    public ConsultarRecibosPendientesRes ConsultarRecibosPendientes(@WebParam( name = "oReq") 
                                                                    ConsultarRecibosPendientesReq objeto) {

        ConsultarRecibosPendientesRes recibosRes = new ConsultarRecibosPendientesRes();

        String LlaveAcceso = objeto.getStrLlaveAcceso();
        recibosRes.setStrIdentificacion(LlaveAcceso);

        return recibosRes;
    }
```

Class of the object that is received by parameter:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ConsultarRecibosPendientesReq")
public class ConsultarRecibosPendientesReq {

    @XmlElement(name = "strLlaveAcceso")
    protected String strLlaveAcceso;

    public ConsultarRecibosPendientesReq(){ }

    public String getStrLlaveAcceso() {
        return strLlaveAcceso;
    }

    public void setStrLlaveAcceso(String strLlaveAcceso) {
        this.strLlaveAcceso = strLlaveAcceso;
    }
}
```

The object QueryReceivePendientesReq is always null. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I made some changes in the class of the object that is received by parameter:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "consultarRecibosPendientesReq", propOrder = {
    "strLlaveAcceso"
})
public class ConsultarRecibosPendientesReq {

    protected String strLlaveAcceso;

    public String getStrLlaveAcceso() {
        return strLlaveAcceso;
    }
    public void setStrLlaveAcceso(String value) {
        this.strLlaveAcceso = value;
    }
}
```

I made a change to the WebService method:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "ConsultarRecibosPendientes")
@WebResult(name = "ConsultarRecibosPendientesResult")
public ConsultarRecibosPendientesRes ConsultarRecibosPendientes(
                                        @WebParam(name = "oReq", targetNamespace = "")
                                        ConsultarRecibosPendientesReq oReq) {...}
```

And finally, I made a change to the XML that is sent, I added the "web" clause to the "method" and "target name space" tags, example:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <web:ConsultarRecibosPendientes xmlns:web="http://websercice.fi.co/">
            <oReq>
                <strLlaveAcceso>llave de acceso</strLlaveAcceso>
            </oReq>
        </web:ConsultarRecibosPendientes>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```